# Can I customize any WordPress parent block-based theme template files by child theme like a parent classic theme?

Tags: theme-development, block-editor, child-theme, parent-theme

Usually, I can replace the template files and PHP codes of any parent classic theme with child themes. Since block-based theme templates rely on HTML, how can I replace parent block-based theme files and code with child themes?